# move all multer uploaded files to a new destination in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, fs, multer

I'm trying to create an upload form that has two fields (select file to upload from your pc and the a dropdown menu with a couple of destinations on the server folder1, folder2, folder3). for this I'm using multer and express

I want the user to be able to upload multiple files at once and the user has a dropdown menu to choose where to store his files on the server. Since the user will give us the path in the form, so I must upload the files to temp folder then move them to the user's chosen destination.

I found a lot of solutions when uploading a single file, but I don't know how to do this with multiple files.

Here's the code I'm using

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});


var temppath = './uploads';


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        var dir = temppath;
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        callback(null, dir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);

    }
});

var fs = require('fs')

app.use( express.static( "public" ) );


var upload = multer({storage: storage}).array('files', 12);
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.end("Something went wrong:(");
            //console.log (req.body);
        }
        res.end("Upload completed.");
        console.log (req.body.pathselector) ;
        //move file from tempfolder to choosen path
        //'req.body.pathselector' is the path that the user will choose from the upload form
        //sth like fs.rename from temppath/filename to req.body.pathselector/same_filename (no need to rename files);




    });
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log("runnig on :3000");
```

hope someone can help with this, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

basically it's the same commands you might use to move a single file, but you will have to loop through the array of files.

the logic is:

```
res.end("Upload completed.");
        newDest = req.body.pathselector ;

        filesArray = req.files ;

        //move file from tempfolder to choosen path
        //'req.body.pathselector' is the path that the user will choose from the upload form
        //sth like fs.rename from temppath/filename to req.body.pathselector/same_filename (no need to rename files);

        for (var item in filesArray) {
        var oldPath = filesArray[item].path;
        // the delimiter is usually / but on windows it's \
        if ( os.platform() == 'Windows_NT'){
            var delimiterOFthisOS = '\\';
        }else{
            var delimiterOFthisOS = '/';
        }

        var newPath = newDest + delimiterOFthisOS + filesArray[item].filename ;

        fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err
          console.log('Successfully renamed - AKA moved!')
        })
```